# safari/opera session cookie deleted prematurely

Tags: php, session, cookies, safari, opera

I've set a PHP session cookie with lifetime 0 (to expire on browser close) but I've been getting logged out of the session after only a few seconds.

I am observing the safari cookies popup window (in safari preferences) and while reloading the page I see the cookie vanish from the list only to be replaced by a new session id when being redirected to the login page (where a new session is started and thus cookie set).

This behaves the same way with opera.
Firefox is fine however.  In fact I've been using the site for a while without any trouble in firefox so if it were to affect it too I would have seen it by now.

I have tried tooling with numerous HTTP headers like Cache-control, checked that `session_write_close()` is in the right spots (but really this shouldn't matter because I'm just refreshing the page), also I checked the session garbage clean up settings, but when I saw these cookies vanish on their own I almost jumped out of my socks!

mac 10.6.4
opera 10.10
safari 5.0.2

I should also mention this site has ajax requests going on, though none of them attempt to destroy the session or remove the cookie in any way (directly).

EDIT: Just tested on win XP: FF okay, Safari same phenonmenon as on Mac.

EDIT: [This short video](http://dailyraisin.com/safari-cookie-bug.html) illustrates this issue on Windows.

Comment: Any live URLs available for us to test and replicate the issue? You have worked hard to describe it well, but, if a picture is worth a thousand words, a living, breathing script is worth a million.

Comment: Have you tried to set the expire to nothing instead of 0?

Comment: I tried setting to some future date (10000 seconds) but I saw the same behavior.  Will work on the image/video demo.

Comment: While the video illustrates the issue, it doesn't give us much to go on. Could you examine your header traffic in Opera DragonFly? (debug => open dragonfly => network => raw)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this thread:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4032092

My best answer is, instead of setting no expiration, set an explicit date/time in the future.